# Make some corrections about a relative complex matrix

Tags: matrices, line-spacing, tikz-matrix, bordermatrix

I have received a relative complex matrix made with Tikz. I would like to do some modifications
on a few points.

Here the source :

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor, scalefnt}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric,trees, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{xfakebold}

\newcommand{\fbseries}{\unskip\setBold\aftergroup\unsetBold\aftergroup\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setBoldness}[1]{\def\fake@bold{#1}}
\makeatother
%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{cczzff}{rgb}{0.8,0.6,1}
\definecolor{ffffww}{rgb}{1,1,0.4}
\definecolor{zzffzz}{rgb}{0.6,1,0.6}
\definecolor{bcduew}{rgb}{0.7372549019607844,0.8313725490196079,0.9019607843137255}
\definecolor{ffzzqq}{rgb}{1,0.6,0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.7]
\fill[line width=1.6pt,color=ffzzqq,fill=ffzzqq,fill opacity=0.28] (-3.9889680326169636,4.401999403915503) -- (-4,2) -- (0,2) -- (0.004889672914417752,4.38116188545186) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=2pt,color=bcduew,fill=bcduew,fill opacity=0.45] (0,2) -- (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=2pt,color=zzffzz,fill=zzffzz,fill opacity=0.44] (3,0) -- (5.5,0) -- (5.5,-2) -- (3,-2) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=2pt,color=ffffww,fill=ffffww,fill opacity=0.45] (5.5,-2) -- (5.5,-4) -- (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319) -- (7.649966897383555,-1.9627139676675045) -- cycle;
\fill[line width=2pt,color=cczzff,fill=cczzff,fill opacity=0.37] (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319) -- (7.597052906560133,-8.992085299292388) -- (13,-9) -- (13,-4) -- cycle;
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=ffzzqq] (-3.9889680326169636,4.401999403915503)-- (-4,2);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=ffzzqq] (-4,2)-- (0,2);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=ffzzqq] (0,2)-- (0.004889672914417752,4.38116188545186);
\draw [line width=1.6pt,color=ffzzqq] (0.004889672914417752,4.38116188545186)-- (-3.9889680326169636,4.401999403915503);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=bcduew] (0,2)-- (0,0);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=bcduew] (0,0)-- (3,0);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=bcduew] (3,0)-- (3,2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=bcduew] (3,2)-- (0,2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzffzz] (3,0)-- (5.5,0);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzffzz] (5.5,0)-- (5.5,-2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzffzz] (5.5,-2)-- (3,-2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=zzffzz] (3,-2)-- (3,0);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffffww] (5.5,-2)-- (5.5,-4);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffffww] (5.5,-4)-- (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffffww] (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319)-- (7.649966897383555,-1.9627139676675045);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffffww] (7.649966897383555,-1.9627139676675045)-- (5.5,-2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=cczzff] (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319)-- (7.597052906560133,-8.992085299292388);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=cczzff] (7.597052906560133,-8.992085299292388)-- (13,-9);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=cczzff] (13,-9)-- (13,-4);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=cczzff] (13,-4)-- (7.622446543428001,-4.014932473190319);
\draw (-3.6,3.9) node[anchor=north west] {\shortstack{\bm{$7\times7$}\\ \textbf{cosmo param}}};
\draw (-0.1,2.1) node[anchor=north west] {\shortstack{\bm{$5\times5$}\\ \textbf{bias spectro}}};
\draw (3.4,-0.3) node[anchor=north west] {\shortstack{\bm{$5\times5$}\\ \textbf{P$_{\textbf{shot}}$}}};
\draw (5.8,-2.4) node[anchor=north west] {\shortstack{\bm{$3\times3$}\\ \textbf{I.A}}};
\draw (9.1,-5.5) node[anchor=north west] {\shortstack{\bm{$11 \times 11$} \\\textbf{bias photo}}};
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4.460513357849706,-9.994562463165211)-- (-5.4826322264884935,-10.009164161288624);
\draw [line width=2pt] (14,-10)-- (12.977881131361215,-10.014601698123412);
\draw [line width=2pt] (14.007084672527233,4.785070169271532)-- (12.993609515251185,4.797912254724703);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-4.493367178627381,4.817923990049208)-- (-5.515486047266167,4.803322291925796);
\draw [line width=2pt] (-5.515486047266167,4.803322291925796)-- (-5.4826322264884935,-10.009164161288624);
\draw [line width=2pt] (14,-10)-- (14.000418558780272,4.785154637846578);
\draw [line width=2pt] (10.604542109871408,4.5248478029740395)-- (10.580442621705167,1.4004721316746256);
\draw [line width=2pt] (1.5901203468644618,-7.3314334586139)-- (1.5237172386414934,-9.747252274283294);
\draw (-5.917619183528533,-12) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F[7+i,7+i] = F[7+i,7+i] + C_{00}$}};
\draw (-1.0432312316260273,-10.389231296495183) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F[25+i,7+i] = F[25+i,7+i] + C_{10}$}};
\draw (2.9205567732177684,6) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F[7+i,25+i] = F[7+i,25+i] + C_{01}$}};
\draw (3.590115557819761,-13.2) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F[25+i,25+i] = F[25+i,25+i] + C_{11}$}};
\draw [shift={(-58.27706376491269,15.519996579460745)},line width=2pt]  plot[domain=5.825732351019411:6.031277023379088,variable=\t]({1*61.3814031943808*cos(\t r)+0*61.3814031943808*sin(\t r)},{0*61.3814031943808*cos(\t r)+1*61.3814031943808*sin(\t r)});
\draw [shift={(3.8,-8)},line width=2pt]  plot[domain=-0.8511778320660293:0.0861746394516815,variable=\t]({1*6.5859837516263235*cos(\t r)+0*6.5859837516263235*sin(\t r)},{0*6.5859837516263235*cos(\t r)+1*6.5859837516263235*sin(\t r)});
\draw [line width=2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 1pt] (-3.5995625932969295,1.6682719831703405)-- (-3.6239203207161172,-8.154457534536574);
\draw (-3.3,-8) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F_{30,0}$}};
\draw [line width=2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 1pt] (-1.339432884578692,-8.594108272555605)-- (7.107327748196611,-8.598793429321976);
\draw [line width=2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 1pt] (12.645679320017997,-3.702365541683961)-- (12.654324456818385,3.0947358918642);
\draw [line width=2pt,dash pattern=on 3pt off 1pt] (12,4)-- (0.4085772595325554,3.978047491580542);
\draw (11.4,-7.9) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F_{30,30}$}};
\draw (11.78551508134815,4) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F_{0,30}$}};
\draw (-3.8,4.3) node[anchor=north west] {\bm{$F_{0,0}$}};
\draw [line width=2pt,dotted] (1.841125022717117,-7.158251757187386)-- (10.141023533796332,-7.186724822405498);
\draw [line width=2pt,dotted] (1.581837717642849,-6.783679416624932)-- (1.651036479690521,0.6897868845235751);
\draw [line width=2pt,dotted] (10.164911093537606,0.9926765325987955)-- (2.0000122864095315,0.9856740464863375);
\draw [line width=2pt,dotted] (10.441106835113134,0.5810006685643927)-- (10.373330191856859,-6.772765124741283);
\draw [color=ffqqqq](1.3483501837473617,1.4) node[anchor=north west] {\large{\bm{$\displaystyle \times$}}};
\draw [color=ffqqqq](1.1,-6.6) node[anchor=north west] {\large{\bm{$\displaystyle \times$}}};
\draw [color=ffqqqq](10,1.4) node[anchor=north west] {\large{\bm{$\displaystyle \times$}}};
\draw [color=ffqqqq](9.990547117115293,-6.6) node[anchor=north west] {\large{\bm{$\displaystyle \times$}}};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=ududff,shift={(10.604542109871408,4.5248478029740395)}] (0,0) ++(0 pt,6pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,-9pt)--++(-10.392304845413264pt,0 pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,9pt);
\draw [fill=ududff,shift={(1.5237172386414934,-9.747252274283294)},rotate=180] (0,0) ++(0 pt,6pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,-9pt)--++(-10.392304845413264pt,0 pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,9pt);
\draw [fill=ududff,shift={(-3.2068752669835625,-11.589983075893043)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,6pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,-9pt)--++(-10.392304845413264pt,0 pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,9pt);
\draw [fill=ududff,shift={(8.2,-12.9)},rotate=270] (0,0) ++(0 pt,6pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,-9pt)--++(-10.392304845413264pt,0 pt) -- ++(5.196152422706632pt,9pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.635718248347523,-4.231629291141428) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.636800539351324,-7.57083005047046) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (11.679065808287241,-8.596069520534554) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-0.3010667528589086,3.9624930510918492) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-2.710381685328957,3.986377828225564) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.605372373467905,3.793610603087946) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.6089348841175433,2.1750609515582267) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (8.33807909606156,-8.59947608901317) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (8.676244295359405,-8.599131285813481) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (8.993690318277086,-8.598807608496424) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (9.412697837028288,-8.598380376086174) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (9.86980871751748,-8.597914292365754) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (10.212570674682693,-8.597564802176322) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (10.55541030806792,-8.597215232785928) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (11.366699452972995,-8.596388018472872) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.6067967704955475,3.146466625296727) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.607671716191231,2.7489539747730274) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.636678791654719,-7.195200945614188) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.636523730787035,-6.716790457778029) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.636377048871235,-6.26423161464287) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.636201032473926,-5.721166870048644) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.63606692713587,-5.307410638970552) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.6359453943006,-4.932444447446744) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.635840624802379,-4.60919830866198) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (12.634549814372313,-7.919278259229274) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-1.264769568315113,3.9720467323728212) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-1.7324630796571368,3.9766832185103294) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-2.242232709994738,3.9863778282255593) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-0.7138639964036116,3.986377828225564) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.605372373467905,2.4580091146344496) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (-3.619141460977735,3.504459765381519) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (10.934226111965524,-8.596828981032205) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following rendering :

[image: matrix]

Modifications to apply :

1. I have marked in red the 2 sections to modify : I need the same size for the text $F_{0,O}$ $F_{30,30}$, $F_{0,30}$ and $F_{30,0}$. But on the upper left, $F_{0,0}$ is overlapped with the dots and is not seen. for this 7x7 block, I need 6 dots line besides to the right inside and 6 dots column below also inside this block. I would like to avoid the overlapping between $F_{0,0}$ and the line/columns of 6 dots.
2. for red marked area on bottom right, I would like to align vertically $F_{30,30}$ with the 10 dots horizontally placed : these 10 dots are too much shifted to the right, so there is a little space between the left side of this 11x11 block and the begin of the 10 dots line. If we could remove this space, then, I could have a good alignment for $F_{30,30}$.
3. and Finally, the blue marked area corresponds to an issue of overlapping also : I would like that the text "bias spectro" to be a little bit higher, above the red cross in order to avoid having an overlap between this text and the red cross.

All these modifications are minor but necessary and I have not enough Tikz skills to solve it by myself.

So any help would be fine.

Comment: Hello. The code you provide is clearly coming from an automatic export from some external software. It's really redundant and it could be interesting to clean it a bit. All the dots are drawn in the end with lines starting with `\draw [fill=black]`. It's possible to delete some of them. For the rest, a close look at the code should be self explanatory if you want to drag some text. Maybe you could give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is from a tool, so it's difficult to modify.

I did it completely new, hoping to meet your needs:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.8,0.6,1}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1,1,0.4}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.6,1,0.6}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.7372549019607844,0.8313725490196079,0.9019607843137255}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,0.6,0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style n args={3}{
        draw=#1,  fill=#1!#2, 
        text width=#3, minimum height=#3,very thick, text centered, text=black, font=\bfseries, 
        line width=2pt, inner sep=0pt,
        anchor=north west
        },
    mydotline/.style={dotted, line width=2pt},
    myline/.style={line width=2pt},
    myarrow/.style={-{Triangle[fill=myblue,line width=1pt]},myline}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
    \node[mynode={myorange}{28}{28mm}] (cosmo) {$\boldsymbol{7\times7}$\\cosmo\\ param};
    \node[mynode={mygray}{45}{20mm}] (spectro) at (cosmo.south east) {$\boldsymbol{5\times5}$\\bias spectro};
    \node[mynode={mygreen}{45}{20mm}] (P) at (spectro.south east) {$\boldsymbol{5\times5}$\\$\mathbf{P_{shot}}$};
    \node[mynode={myyellow}{44}{12mm}] (IA) at (P.south east) {$\boldsymbol{3\times3}$\\I.A};
    \node[mynode={myviolet}{37}{44mm}] (photo) at (IA.south east) {$\boldsymbol{11\times11}$\\bias photo};
    \node[red, anchor=south] (Xspectro) at (spectro.south) {$\boldsymbol{\times}$};
    \node[red, anchor=south] (Xphoto) at ([yshift=2.7cm]photo.south) {$\boldsymbol{\times}$};
    \draw[mydotline] (Xspectro) -| node[fill=white, text=red] (XsXp) {$\boldsymbol{\times}$}  (Xphoto);
    \draw[mydotline] (Xspectro) |- node[fill=white, text=red] (XpXs)  {$\boldsymbol{\times}$}  (Xphoto);
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=4pt] (Fcosmo) at (cosmo.north west) {$\boldsymbol{F_{0,0}}$};
    \node[anchor=south east, inner sep=4pt] (Fphoto) at (photo.south east) {$\boldsymbol{F_{30,30}}$};
    \draw[mydotline] (Fcosmo) -| node[fill=white] (FNE) {$\boldsymbol{F_{0,30}}$}  (Fphoto);
    \draw[mydotline] (Fcosmo) |- node[fill=white] (FSW) {$\boldsymbol{F_{30,0}}$}  (Fphoto);
    \draw[myarrow] (Xspectro.west) -- +(-3,-11.5) node[anchor=170] {$\boldsymbol{F[7+i,7+i] = F[7+i,7+i] + C_{00}}$};
    \draw[myarrow] (XpXs) -- +(0,-4cm) node[anchor=170] {$\boldsymbol{F[25+i,7+i] = F[25+i,7+i] + C_{10}}$};
    \draw[myarrow] (XsXp) -- +(0,5.5) node[anchor=-10] {$\boldsymbol{F[7+i,25+i] = F[7+i,25+i] + C_{01}}$};
    \draw[myarrow] (Xphoto.east) to[out=-10, in=0] +(1.5, -5.5) node[anchor=east] {$\boldsymbol{F[25+i,25+i] = F[25+i,25+i] + C_{11}}$};
    \draw[myline] ([shift={(-.4,.6)}]Fcosmo.center) -- ([shift={(-.9,.6)}]Fcosmo.center) -- ([shift={(-.9,-.6)}]FSW.center) -- +(.5,0) ;
    \draw[myline] ([shift={(.4,.6)}]FNE.center) -- ([shift={(.9,.6)}]FNE.center) -- ([shift={(.9,-.6)}]Fphoto.center) -- +(-.5,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]